# Selenium WebDriver Java - can't get dynamic text from span tag

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

Trying to get numeric dynamic text value from span element. My test is data driven so for each run it needs to get text (dollar amount) from web page and then compare it to expected value in excel. For some reason my code doesn't work. Please help to solve.

My HTML:

$
445.87

My Locator: By PRICE = By.xpath("//div[@class='price ng-binding'][@ng-hide='calc.isCalculating']/text()");

My Code:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15); 
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(PRICE));

    WebElement actualPriceElm = driver.findElement(PRICE);
    actualPriceElm.getText();

    Assert.assertEquals(actualPriceElm, strExpectedPrice);
```

My Error: Timed out after 15 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //div[@class='price ng-binding'][@ng-hide='calc.isCalculating']/text()

When I use my xpath without "/text()" like this //div[@class='price ng-binding'][@ng-hide='calc.isCalculating'] then I get following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: expected [445.87] but found [[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (f26e0c00-823f-4d45-8285-014303527524)] -> xpath: //div[@class='price ng-binding'][@ng-hide='calc.isCalculating']]]

Comment: Here is HTML: <div class="price ng-binding" ng-hide="calc.isCalculating">
<span class="dollarSign">$</span>
445.87
<span class="dollarSign"/>
</div>

Comment: prior to the wait, what causes the element to appear? in manual testing, what would you do to make the dynamic element present?

Comment: Try using `By.CssSelector()`

Comment: Charlie, there is a bunch of radio buttons that I select prior to wait. Their combination will result in different pricing. There is clearly issue with my locator and not with the code. For some reason xpath is not working. I will try css as Vikram suggested.

Comment: using http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath, i can extract the value you want from the HTML you provide, using the xpath you have specified

Comment: http://www.xpathtester.com/colored/01bcc904adbb268b6e459a28e5140112

Comment: I am not sure if your xpath is right. Can you share the link of AUT?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot share the link to AUT - it's internal you won't be able to access it. It looks like my xpath is correct after all. Not sure why it's not working.

Comment: how do you perform the clicks? can you break (debug) on the wait construction and inspect that the elements are there.  Clicking radio buttons doesn't usually do anything that needs to be waited for, they have immediate affect. If they are only changing prices, why do you expect the presence of an element to change, rather than it's value?  Maybe post some page source, it's not sounding very dynamic the way you have explained it so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. As Vikram mentioned in his comment I had to use cssSelector instead of xPath.

By.cssSelector("div.priceLine:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2)");
VS.
By.xpath("//div[@class='price ng-binding'][@ng-hide='calc.isCalculating']");

Thanks everyone for your suggestions and input.

Answer (score 0):

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);

// DO SOMETHING HERE TO CAUSE ELEMENT TO BE DISPLAYED (ie click, hover, mousemove, etc)

wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='price ng-binding'][@ng-hide='calc.isCalculating']/text()"))).isDisplayed();
    }
});
```

Comment: For some reason I cannot plug this piece of code. I get following: The method until(Function<? super WebDriver,T>) in the type Wait<WebDriver> is not applicable for the arguments (new Function<WebDriver,Boolean>(){}). Which Function package is that?

Comment: you can use your own wait.until(), the point is to do something to cause the page to dynamically update..

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath `//div[@class='price ng-binding'][@ng-hide='calc.isCalculating']/text()` returns text 445.87 while you need to find WebElement and get its text. Did you try to use `Assert.assertEquals(actualPriceElm.getText(), "445.87");`?

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but no luck again.                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(PRICE, expectedPrice));
WebElement actualPriceElm = driver.findElement(PRICE);
Assert.assertEquals(actualPriceElm.getText(), expectedPrice);   Error I'm getting: Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for text ('445.87') to be present in element found by By.xpath: //div[@class='price ng-binding'][@ng-hide='calc.isCalculating']